# Editable textbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on Asp.net MVC4 application.
I have user's information and edit button in case any user wants to edit his/her information.

A user can edit his/her information by double clicking on it also.
Suppose if a username is there then user can edit it by clicking double on it. As soon as he clicks on UserName it is editable with its value in a textbox.

How can i make value editable with textbox?

I tried-

```
$(function(){
    $('.double').on('dblclick',function(){
        var val=$(this).html();
        $(this).append('<input type="text" value=val/>');
    });
});
```

But no success.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKAvs/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [contentEditable   attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#contenteditable)

```
$(".double").get(0).contentEditable = "true";
```

> the contenteditable attribute is an enumerated attribute whose keywords are the empty string, true, and false. The empty string and the true keyword map to the true state. The false keyword maps to the false state. In addition, there is a third state, the inherit state, which is the missing value default (and the invalid value default).

[**DEMO1  |**](http://jsfiddle.net/wKAvs/4/)
 [**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/wKAvs/15/)

Comment: This is awesome, Thanks for letting me know something new today.

Comment: is `get(0)` meant by length of content?

Comment: No.not the content ,its 0 th element in the selector.otherwise ,the div's all have the class 'double' become editable.

Comment: You will come to know the difference if you have multiple divs with same class name .where get(0) selects the first div.

Comment: Then how can i do this for all the elements if i don't use `get()`?

Comment: But that is for getting index, I need to edit each an every element of same class.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

Use [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

```
$(document).on('dblclick', '.double' function() {
    var val = $(this).text();
    $(this).replaceWith('<input type="text" value="' + val + '" class="username" />');
});
```

And to revert back to div:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.username', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(this).replaceWith('<div class="double">' + val + '</div>');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wKAvs/9/)

Comment: corrected your JS, added class to input and remove incorrectly escaped quotes

Comment: You need event delegation again for the edit, because they are dynanamically generated

Comment: @DKM, Thank you DKM  but suresh's answer is more precise and short to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('.double').on('dblclick',function(){
        var val=$(this).text();
        $(this).append('<input type="text" value=\"' + val + '\" />');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but how i don't really want to append textbox. Is there any other way to just edit value without appending this textbox?

Comment: @Manoz check my answer for that

Answer (score 0):

You just need to concatenate `val` properly:

```
$(this).append('<input type="text" value="'+val+'">');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/wKAvs/3/