# Is there a way to create the stackoverfow "Tags" EditText/Input field in Android?

Tags: java, android, view, textview

I want to know If there is a way to create a EditText like the stackoverflow EditText in Android:
[image: Stackoverflow tags TextView]

**Questions:**

1. How is this called? so I can search it on google
2. Is there any library out there already?
3. If there isn't, where should I start with making one myself?

Comment: You probably mean an `EditText`.

Comment: In Web there is [contentEditable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085463/editable-textbox-in-jquery/18085490#18085490) , No idea about Android. Is it in browser ?

Comment: No it is native Android.

Comment: You can do it with AutoCompleteTextView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it by searching "android tag editor textview" and I came along this: http://www.kpbird.com/2013/02/android-chips-edittext-token-edittext.html

So **Stackoverflow tags field is Chips EditText in Android.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a Database that will listen to the keys events and using pattern matching, fetch out the data from database.

When you select the data, the data will be stored in a button or whatever.